# How to update a textarea with vue.js based on multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js

Just like the title says, I'm trying to update a `textarea` based off multiple inputs. I have that part working (with line-breaks) using jQuery, however when I try to get the value of that `textarea` and display it elsewhere using vue.js, it doesn't work. Even weirder, when I edit the vue.js data-bound fields, it erases the `textarea` until the inputs are re-edited. I'm new to vue.js so I'm a little confused as to what's happening here. Any help is appreciated.

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tyk6tb22/) with the same code as below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change keyup', 'input.url-field', function() {
    var inputs = $('input.url-field');
    var textareaVal = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      textareaVal += $(inputs[i]).val() + "\r\n";
    }
    $('textarea#urls').val(textareaVal);
  });
  // vue.js app
  new Vue({
    el: '#all',
    data: {
      phone: '',
      urls: ''
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input, textarea{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="all">
  <form>
    <label>Phone:</label>
    <input name="phone" v-model="phone" type="text">
    <label>URL1:</label>
    <input class="url-field" name="url1" type="text">
    <label>URL2:</label>
    <input class="url-field" name="url2" type="text">
    <textarea id="urls" name="urls" v-model="urls" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
  </form>
  <br>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Phone:</strong></td>
      <td>{{ phone }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>URLs:</strong></td>
      <td>{{ urls }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to be able to edit the textarea or is it just a display field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `textarea` as just a display field. Try this. Essentially, abandon using jQuery and let Vue manage the `textarea`.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#all',
  data: {
    phone: '',
    url1: null,
    url2: null
  },
  computed:{
      urls(){
        return [this.url1, this.url2].join("\r\n")
      }
  }
});
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tyk6tb22/1/).

If you wanted to be able to edit the textarea to add urls, you might try something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tyk6tb22/3/).

Comment: Actually, there's just one issue. The 'url1', 'url2', etc. inputs are dynamically added with no defined limit. Each one is sequential in name, so the next one would be:

`<input class="url-field" name="url3" type="text">`

So on and so forth. Is there an easy way to manage that using your method without having to define each one?

Comment: @Aender If you look at the second example (click `this` in the last sentence) I provide you with a way to handle any number of urls.

Comment: I didn't even see that. Thanks!